# Giving WordPress Its Own Directory together with index.html

Tags: directory

I want to power my website from `http://www.example.com` and not from `http://www.example.com/foldername`

I've completed this task and this is working but before people actually get to the WordPress website they must pass another website-page. See the scheme below.

`www.example.com`: shows a page with some information and a link to navigate to the wp site.

My problem now is that when I follow the steps on http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory, my index file is fighting with the one from WordPress. I hope people understand the problem.

**EDIT**

Changing `.htaccess` to:

```
DirectoryIndex home.htm index3.php index.htm index.html default.htm
```

This is working to change the homepage, but as soon you are on the WordPress website and you click on home in the menu, you get back to the homepage set in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Why don't you change the menu to point to index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to put in your functions.php file, it will show the splash-page.php only to outside visitors (by checking the referer). Make a splash-page.php in your current theme directory and edit the domain (example.com) in the code:

```
add_action('template_redirect','my_splash_page');      
function my_splash_page(){ 
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $referer_parse = parse_url($referer);
    if(is_front_page()){
        // let visitors see the normal wordpress homepage if they are browsing your web
        if($referer_parse['host'] == "example.com" || $referer_parse['host'] == "www.example.com") {

        // let visitors see the splash page if they are visiting directly or from another pages
        } else {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/splash-page.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Birgire what is the difference between example.com and www.example.com in your example.

Comment: it's just to cover both cases ;-)  It's different between sites if they use www or not.

Comment: Can we continue in chat?

Comment: ps: please remember to vote on the answer, since we managed to solve it with this method, thanks ;-)